# netlogo export viewer with zoom level

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know if there is a "primitive" way for export view around a specified agents in netlogo.

Something like

[image: zoom on agents]

rather than

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetLogo doesn't have this feature, nor do I know of an extension which offers it.

NetLogo's rendering engine is capable of this. So you could do it from Java, using either the [Extensions API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API) or the [Controlling API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API).